# How to sort the join data?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my request, I join the data of the users model in this way

```
 ...
 include: [{ model: User, attributes: ['username'], required: true }],
 ...
```

And when I want to sort the data an error 500 occurs.

```
...    
order: [... ['user.username', req.query.order], ...]
...
```

How to link to sorting correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this below code as explained in the doc : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#relations---associations

```
order: [[User, 'username', req.query.order]]
```